# obtener latitud y longitud (posicion) google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

me gustaría poder determinar mi actual localización en un proyecto android, para así poder obtener la latitud y longitud de mi posición para usarlos en un método en especifico, he revisado las preguntas resueltas, pero no entiendo el código que han dado como respuesta, si pudieran darme una mano, se los agradecería

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como en unas de las respuestas que te dieron en otras preguntas, se utiliza `LocationManager`

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

Esto te traera la posicion actual, de no haber una posicion actual devolvera null obviamente pero hay un metodo que hace este trabajo de forma asincrona

```
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }
}

lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
```

---

**Como obtener latitud y longitud al iniciar la aplicación:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    if (location != null) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);
```

Comment: me devolvio la longitud como nula y creo que lo mismo la latitud

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta

Comment: eso lo puedo poner en un onCreate o es un método aparte?

Comment: Si te fijas, se declara la funcion y a tu objeto LocationManager se llama la funcion, asi que puedes definirla y llamar desde un onCreate

Comment: no entiendo como utilizarlo, sinceramente

Comment: Que no entiendes @zhet ?

Comment: como utilizar el código de la actualización que hiciste, las respuestas que vi utilizanban ese o un código parecido, y como dice mi pregunta, no entendí  en si como utilzarlo, no se como definirlo dentro de la clase

Comment: gracias, por darte el tiempo de ayudarme, el metodo requestLocationUpdates no me lo reconoce

Comment: no, no funciona, sabes el import exacto que deberia usar?

Comment: me genera 2, pero probe con los 2 y aun si, me muestra en rojo el metodo requestLocationUpdates

Comment: estoy usando la api 24

Comment: @siosis, gracias me funciono perfecto

Comment: @zhet excelente! Voy a borrar los comentarios, para que no los trasladen a chat, saludos!

Comment: Amigo @sioesi edité un pic tu respuesta.

Comment: Gracias @Elenasys por la edicion! Un abrazo!

Comment: tengo un error en esta parte locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this); en la parte de this me marca error alguien sabe por que?

Answer (score -2):

Viste la documentación de apache cordova? ahí sale como hacerlo, yo lo logre pero en ionic. Te dejo el link, saludos.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/